# unrecognized selector while calling using addTarget

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, uitableview

I am using addTarget on custom cell button like:

```
[cell.btnGet addTarget:self action:@selector(getLocal:cell:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

It should be call this method:

```
-(void)getLocal:(id)sender withcell:(GroupListCell *)cell
{
    // code for implement
}
```

but when I am click the button it is throwing error like:

```
2013-02-27 14:28:56.533 iOSPlayer[704:11303] -[GroupView getLocal:cell:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x72e1290
2013-02-27 14:28:56.534 iOSPlayer[704:11303] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[GroupView getLocal:cell:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x72e1290'
```

What is the issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
[cell.btnGet addTarget:self action:@selector(getLocal:withcell:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Answer (score 1):

That action method is called:

```
getLocal:withcell:
```

and not:

```
getLocal:cell:
```

It also doesn't match any of the acceptable action method signatures, which are:

```
- (IBAction)doSomething;
- (IBAction)doSomething:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)action:(id)sender forEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
```

(see this [Apple guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/Devpedia-CocoaApp/TargetAction.html))